# How do I add a label to a vBox?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm having some problem statically adding a label to an fxml file. Here is what I tried, but it does not work, `placeholder` is highlighted in red. I basically want a header/title for my list view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import java.awt.Label?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <placeholder>
        <Label text="some text"/>
    </placeholder>
    <ListView fx:id="groupListView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
</VBox>
```

Comment: Try using SceneBuilder. Also, you are trying to add an `awt` label. You should be adding a `JavaFX` label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had the wrong import, and there was no need for placeholder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
        <Label text="some text"/>
    <ListView fx:id="groupListView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
</VBox>
```